# When do you use (( )) or /usr/bin/test

Tags: shell, unix

I have seen scripts using the `test` command and `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`. But when do we need to use `/usr/bin/test` and `(( ))`?

Are there any occasions when we need to go for the latter?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To answer your question:

- you want to use `/usr/bin/test` when you want to `test` something but not in a shell (for example `find ... -exec test ...`)
- you want to use `(( ))` when you have an arithmetic expression to solve, AND you are using bash, because `(( ))` is bash specific.

Now for some background:

The command `/usr/bin/test` is required by the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard. POSIX also requires that `[` is defined as an alias for `test`. The only difference between `test` and `[` is that `[` requires the final parameter to be a `]`.

Since `test` is used so frequently in shell scripts, most shells have a builtin version of `test` (and `[`). The advantage of a builtin is that it avoids [context switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch). Which, depending how you use `test` in your script, can be a measurable performance advantage.

I think it is safe to assume that under most circumstances it doesn't matter whether you use the system `test` or the shell's builtin `test`. But if you want to use `test` in a `find -exec` situation then of course you have to use the system `test` because `find` cannot use the shell `test`.

`(( ))` and `[[ ]]` were introduced by bash (and perhaps some other shells) as [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). `(( ))` evaluates arithmetic expressions, while `[[ ]]` evaluates logical expressions. Both allow you to write the expressions in a "more natural syntax".

The decision to use `[[` or `[` depends on whether you want to use the "more natural syntax", and, since sh does not support `[[`, whether you want to depend on bash.

The decision to use `(( ))` depends on whether you need arithmetic expressions, and again, since sh does not support `(( ))`, whether you want to depend on bash. The POSIX alternative to `(( ))` is `$(( ))`. Note that there are some subtle differences in the behaviour.

The following links explain these topics in great detail:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 (difference between `test`, `[` and `[[`)
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression (`let`, `(( ))` and `$(( ))`)
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/index.html (all of the above)

See also:

- [POSIX definition of `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)
- [POSIX definition of `$(( ))`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04)

Bonus: Some debian developers once argued whether they should use the system `test` or the shell builtin `test`, because of some differences in the implementation of the builtin `test`. If you are interested in details of the differences of the system `test` and the shell builtin `test` then you can read the debian developer discussion here: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=267142.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that zsh and ksh also support `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` (at least the versions I just tried to so).

Answer (score 6):

`(( ))` evaluates an arithmetic expression in `bash` (see `man bash`).
`[[ ]]` evaluates a logic expression in `bash` (see `man bash`).
`[ ]` is the same as `test`, used to *check file types and compare values* (see `man test`).

Answer (score 3):

You use `/usr/bin/test` when you want things to run more slowly.  Modern shells (most shells released since about 1990, probably earlier) have `test` and its synonym `[` as built-in commands.  Formally invoking `/usr/bin/test` would be an act of desparation because the shell has a broken test command and the system standalone is OK - but it would be better to get a fixed shell.

You use `(( ... ))` to do arithmetic.  The old-fashioned alternative was the `expr` command.  That was tricky to use because it required a lot of escaping - it is/was a separate executable, and you had to get lots of shell metacharacters past the shell to `expr`.  Hence:

```
x=$(expr $y '*' $z)
```

instead of

```
((x = y * z))
```

You don't even have to decorate the variables with `$` in `(( ... ))`.

Comment: E.g. I just added /usr/bin/test to a Makefile, because the Makefile doesn't define SHELL, and some users have SHELL=bash, and others SHELL=csh.  So I can't rely on one of the nicer tests, (()) or [[]], being available.  // Of course, you might argue that using Make at all is a bug.  Or at least not define SHELL in make.