# How to test whether a command output is non-empty in POSIX shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, testing

How to efficiently check whether an arbitrary command produced any output in POSIX shell? (Let's say *`git ls-files --killed`*.)

There are three obvious ways, but each seems ugly or evil to me:

1. **[ -n "$(git ls-files --killed)" ]** - the complete output of the command has to be captured in memory and passed to *test* (which is at least hopefully a builtin)
2. **[ "$(git ls-files --killed | wc -c)" -gt 0 ]** - two fork-execs involved
3. **TMP=$(tempfile); git ls-files --killed >"$tempfile"; [ -s "$tempfile" ] && ...; rm "$tempfile"** - an intermediate temporary file (again capturing all the output, too) is required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the exit status of the command also. Usually, commands if successfuly run, return an exit status of 0.

```
git ls-files --killed > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

OR if you want to only depend on the output of the command , you can use the "`head -1`" along with you 1st option since anyway it looks you are not doing any processing with your command output apart from knowing the result.

Comment: git ls-files --killed returns successful regardless of the number of files it finds just like ls.

Comment: Thank you! Obviously, `head -n 1` is exactly what I was missing, perfect.

(Note that I don't consider your first answer that relevant as returning / not returning output is something very different from success / failure. Also, I'd consider it more elegant to use a more succinct version `if git ls-files --killed >/dev/null; then ...; fi`.

Comment: (...though, it also involves two forks. I still think it's the nicest alternative suggested so far, though.)

Answer (score 4):

My preferred solution uses POSIX shell builtin [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html)

```
if git ls-files --killed | read REPLY; then
  echo "Some output"
else
  echo "No output or git failed"
fi
```

`read` attempts to read a line from stdin (and into the variable `REPLY`), and returns 0 if successful, or a positive exit code if failed. The rest of the pipeline is not read. In bash only, `REPLY` is the default name if omitted, so `read REPLY` may be shortened to just `read`.

A potential downside of this approach is that the exit code of the program in question (git in your example) is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

You might think this solution is just as hacky as the others, but I think it uses less memory than the others (I'm no expert in shell script efficiency).

The code is bash only:

```
z=0
while read -r -n1 char; do
  z=1
  break
done < <(git ls-files --killed)
[ $z != 0 ]
```

It uses a temporary variable instead of a temporary file, and I think read works only one char at a time, but the git ls-files command may still execute fully.

It's may not be much less ugly, but I think it may be at least more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice idea; the only big downside is that it is heavily bash-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mention POSIX, I'll refer you to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534891/when-do-you-use-or-usr-bin-test)
I would use /usr/bin/test because it is required on POSIX systems.

`/usr/bin/test -n "$(git ls-files --killed)"`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how is this relevant. POSIX should guarantee plain test / [ to behave appropriately as well, and your solution is then the same as one of mine.

Comment: Agreed. I believe your 1st solution is the best or most efficient, as no forks are created (most likely) and you don't require the output.